# How to get element to line up to outer edge of parent element

Tags: html, css, nav

I am having problems keeping the right edge of the nav lined up with the outer edge of my header. Is there any simple way to fix this so they line up no matter what the browser size is.
My HTML is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Webpage Layout</title>
<style>
* {padding: 0px;}

html {
width: 970px;
margin: auto;
}

header, footer {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
height: 10%;
margin: 5px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

section, nav, aside {
text-align: center;
padding: 0px;
height: 80%;
float: right;
margin: 5px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

section {width: 480px;}

nav, aside {width: 218px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1>Header</h1>
</header>
<aside>
<h1>Aside</h1>
</aside>
<section>
<h1>Section</h1>
</section>
<nav>
<h1>Nav</h1>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Any Help Would be Greatly Appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use flex, this [article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a good start for flex css.

What i did is i wrapped the content into flex-div, namely `body-container`. then i set the flex-grow of the `section` to 2, and `aside` `nav` to 1. so it will be 1:2:1 ratio

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Webpage Layout</title>
  <style>
    * {
      padding: 0px;
    }

    html {
      width: 970px;
      margin: auto;
    }

    .body-container {
      display: flex;
    }
    header, footer {
      text-align: center;
      height: 10%;
      margin: 5px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    section, nav, aside {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 5px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    section {
      flex: 2 0 auto;
    }

    nav, aside {
      flex: 1 0 auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
  <h1>Header</h1>
</header>
<div class="body-container">
  <aside>
    <h1>Aside</h1>
  </aside>
  <section>
    <h1>Section</h1>
  </section>
  <nav>
    <h1>Nav</h1>
  </nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this has fixed the problem. Could you possibly describe how flex works please, as I have never come across this property before.

Comment: u're welcome. the link i posted above is really a good start to know about the flex, you may one to take a look. It works by auto calculating the width/height for the elements, and claims to have good performance too.

Comment: would it be possible to use this same thing with a fixed-position header?

Comment: Sorry @BrianKarl, what do you mean using the same with a fixed- position header? :)

Comment: but what is the purpose of setting that? is it so to make the header is always apperaing on top when u do the scrolling? if it is, you may wan to use the `margin-top` with the height of the header for the `body-container` element, then it shall works

Answer (score 0):

add this property in body.

```
body{  
margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: i tried this, but now it wont line up on the left or the right. Should i possibly use percentages instead of pixels for width?

Comment: you can increase width some (px or percentage) in your section